windows task is still running that is no longer in the task scheduler
I deleted a task from the task scheduler a while back on my server but logs are still being created at the old scheduled time indicating the task is still somehow scheduled to run. How can I find what is causing this task to run in the middle of the night and remove it when it is no longer in the task scheduler?

Check in C:\Windows\System32\Tasks\  as admin to see if that task is partially still there? I've never seen a task run that doesn't show up, so my first guess would be that a different existing task probably runs with the same action

Start monitoring the server with Process Monitor a bit before the "scheduled" time and take a look at the process tree (CTRL-T) to identify the parent process. Maybe it's not the Task Scheduler after all...
